# Stuck on equivalence relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Let R be the relation on the set of ordered pairs of positive integers such that $((a, b), (c, d)) \in R$ if and only if $ad = bc$. What are the equivalence classes of this relation?

I am completely stuck any help would be of a lot of help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Assuming $a,b,c,d \neq 0$,$$
  \frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} \Leftrightarrow ad = bc
$$